# matplotlib.pyplot.imshow awkwardly not plotting all of the data when array is transposed

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot an array full of ones and zeros and most of the time it works well and looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr1fb.jpg).

However, when my array becomes too big (I need to plot 60,000x70) the plot only draws [part of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMt3N.jpg).

At first I thought that this might be some sort of memory issue, but the arrays actually are not that big after all and when looking into memory usage there also was no sign of too heavy lifting.

It becomes really weird, however, when I plot the *transposed* array, because then it works [like a breeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90uXH.jpg).

I looked around in forums quite a lot but apparently nobody else has had such an issue. Might this be a bug? I really need to plot it in the original orientation. So, any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

This exactly reproduces my problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate fake data
a = np.random.random((60000, 70))
for x in np.nditer(a, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    if x > 0.9:
        x[...] = 1
    else:
        x[...] = 0

# plot fake data
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axes[0][0].imshow(a, interpolation='none', cmap='binary', aspect='auto')
axes[0][1].imshow(a.T, interpolation='none', cmap='binary', aspect='auto')
axes[1][0].imshow(a[:30000], interpolation='none', cmap='binary', aspect='auto')
axes[1][1].imshow(a[:30000].T, interpolation='none', cmap='binary', aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

The code yields [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILNtN.jpg). In the upper left subplot everything is plotted. In the plot showing the transposed array (upper right), however, matplotlib only draws the first ~10000 columns. The lower two plots just show the first half of the array (left normal, right transposed) and as you can see, with smaller arrays there is no issue.

**SOLVED**

This problem does not occur with matplotlib 2.x

Comment: This [naive attempt](https://ideone.com/2qTqmY) at reproducing the problem fails (at least for me). Can you help us construct a reproducible example? What is the dtype of `a`? Why is there a pandas tag on this question? How is pandas involved? (Transposing DataFrames can change its columns' dtypes...)

Comment: Please read and understand [mcve]. Then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: The expectation to accurately map 60000 datapoints correctly to ~1000 screenpixels is probably just a bit overoptimistic.

Comment: Sorry for hot having included an reproducible example, I have added one now. The pandas tag was a mistake.

Comment: The output of the code from the question looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F3TG.png) for me - just as expected. This may be an issue of using an old matplotlib version, or a different backend.

Comment: I run matplotlib 1.5.1 in my 'main' environment because I cannot afford to update it. In another environment with matplotlib 2.1.0 it worked without an issue. Thanks for your help! I can't believe how much time I wasted without thinking about testing it with the newest version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]
The problem only occurs with outdated versions of matplotlib.